# driver.get(url); is throwing an exception,"Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died"

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to open `android` default browser in an android device(also firefox, chrome) for selenium automation testing, I have done all the pre-requisites like installing `webdriver`, `selenium-server`, etc., But, when I try to run it, the `webdriver` gets opened and url is also opened, but after that, the line `driver.get(url);` is throwing an exception:

> "Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died"

Comment: How you are detecting device? emulator or real device using usb?

Comment: I am accessing Real Android device using USB from Mac Book

Comment: ok so have you integrated selendroid jar file?

Comment: Please show more code. See [ask] for additional ideas if you want to get better answers.

Comment: webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.2.23:8080/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.android());
.....
webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
webDriver.get(url);


This is the code I am using..

Comment: NO, i have added android.jar and selenium-android-driver.jar

Comment: actually the code seems to work properly before some days with these two jars(android.jar & selenium-android-driver.jar), but now suddenly it is showing this error, the url is getting opened and it is scanning all the elements in the webpage, but the exception is thrown after opening the url.

Comment: I have added selendroid.jar also, but still the exception is thrown

Comment: Also, i want to open firefox and chrome browsers in android device for testing, i am able to open firefox using,

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.mozilla.firefox/.App
but chrome is not opened using,

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.chrome/.Main  
     
How to start firefox and chrome browsers through remote webdriver?.

Comment: I tried like, 
DesiredCapabilities capability =DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
capability.setPlatform(Platform.ANDROID); capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
webdriver=new.RemoteWebdriver(new URL(192.111.2.02:8080/wd/hub), capability); 
but it doesn't work, webdriver is always "null".Whether we have any separate webdrivers for firefox and chrome, that needs to be installed in android device???. Please help me on this.

 Thanks in advance..